# Calling a php file not working inside div

Tags: php, html

I have small project in which i am working with tables inside tabs. In the last table I am trying to call news.php file which will show all the news inside table but no results is showing here. Can anyone know where i am doing wrong? ANd how to call news.php file inside div ? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
// -- REGISTER ERSTELLEN -------------------------------------------------------

$page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
    1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
    0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),   
);

$page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);



// -- HTML AUSGEBEN ------------------------------------------------------------
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                <?php
                require ("news.php");
                ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
?>
```

Comment: See this answer for storing the result from a file to a variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830366/require-once-to-variable You can then put that variable into your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">'.require ("news.php").' </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

You cann't use `<?php` tag inside a `<?php` tag again so remove this

Comment: Hello i have tried in both the ways but its giving error as : Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'news.php </div> </td> </tr> </table>' (include_path='./:/www/1/lang:/www/1/html/admin/includes/addons:/www/1/html/admin/includes/addons/pmail:/www/1/html/admin/includes/addons/fzsuche') in /www/1/html/admin/includes/dashboard.inc

Comment: Did you read the error ? You have to put the path to your "news.php" file correctly.

Comment: @user3702602 it means there is more then one file with the same name so you need to give the full path of this file which you want to include.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows,

```
<?php
// -- REGISTER ERSTELLEN -------------------------------------------------------

$page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
    1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
    0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),   
);

$page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);



// -- HTML AUSGEBEN ------------------------------------------------------------
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">'.

                require ("news.php").'

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Why did you change from `require` to `include`? There is an important difference, which you should at least explain / address in your answer.

Comment: @cale_b, it was by mistake. I would have added explanation had I used 'include' instead of 'require'.

Answer (score 0):

I was making mistake in defining php file. Here is the answer:

```
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">'.require ("news.php").' </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```