# Why I cannot get the return value of require_once function in PHP?

Tags: php, return, require-once

I already know that `include_once` would return `true` or `false` based on including that file. I've read [a question on Stackoverflow about using require_once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830366/require-once-to-variable) to return your value and print it out.

The problem is that I have an existing project in hand, and inside of that file they return an array. I want to get the output of `require_once` to see what result I've got, but I get 1 instead of `array` that contains data:

```
return array('data'=>$result_data,'error'=>null);
```

What I do is:

```
$ret = require_once $this->app->config('eshopBaseDir')."fax/archive.php";
print_r($ret);
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You'll need to run your own tests, but returning from a require is such a marginal feature that it wouldn't surprise me if it doesn't support returning arrays. But fear not, just stick the array in a global variable and fetch it after requiring. PHP's lack of modularity is to your advantage in this case.

Comment: @alexis, it works by using GLOBAL. tnx

Comment: @JohnConde That is incorrect

Comment: @alexis that's no more the case, [things have changed over time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (search for "Handling Returns").

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that returning arrays is supported. (I was guessing back then anyway :-) ).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This indicated that the file has already been included at that point.

require_once will return boolean true if the file has already been included.

To check you can change to simply require:

```
$ret = require $this->app->config('eshopBaseDir')."fax/archive.php";
print_r($ret);
```

As a simple proof:

```
//test.php

return array('this'=>'works the first time');

//index.php

$ret = require_once 'test.php';
var_dump($ret);//array
$ret2 = require_once 'test.php';
var_dump($ret2);//bool true
```